# C# Set Checkbox to Static

Tags: c#, static, checkbox

I have a checkbox that I created to windows forms, how can I set it to static?

```
public static CheckBox checkthis;
```

This code creates a new one as static, what I want to do is set one that I have created in the designer to static.

Update:

I tried below answer and it worked, though the checkbox disappeared from the form and various other issues kicked in. Instead I did this create a new one and did this:

```
public static CheckBox checkthisnew;

...
checkthisnew = checkthis;
```

Either way, I have now realised that I am fail and that I just can use the state changed on the events list, so all is well...

Sorry for not making my reasoning behind this more clear, I do appreciate your answers though, thank you.

Comment: Why do you want this to be static?  There is probably a better way to do what you want...maybe post a little more info on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why in the world would you want your CheckBox to be static in the first place?

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is check its state from another class, and I realised that if it's static then I won't have to create an instance of the class...

Answer (score 2):

Edit the `MyForm.Designer.cs` file, right where the declaration for your checkbox is. Note that your changes will be reverted if you use the designer to modify the UI again so you'll have to do this again.

Comment: @Zizo47 - I am curious as to why you are doing this, though. Make sure you have a read of Jeff's answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing good can come from making a dependent UI control static.  It's one thing to make a component static and that could be ok, but for something like a `CheckBox`, you're just asking for trouble.  For starters, a single control can only have one parent.  So you can't just make a single instance of your control and expect to be able to add it to multiple forms and everything will magically appear to be in sync.  If you need to share some values, do it the right way and bind to them, register some events, share the *value* and not the control that holds the value, or other similar methods.

I also cannot recommend you modify generated files (especially if it's generated from a tool you're using all the time).  If you must insist on making the control static, declare it in *your* source file for the class, not the designer-generated file, the classes are declared `partial` for a reason.

You're probably trying to share some `bool` value that the `CheckBox` represents.  Make *that* a static property.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public static bool IsToggled { get; set; }
}
```

If somewhere down the line you want to tie that to an event or whatever, you could always change the implementation of the accessors.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... without more context, I'd suggest to use a public boolean property for this.
Having a UI item be static is not a good idea.

Try something like this:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public static bool IsWhateverSet {get; private set;}
}
```